How to disable Lean 4's anonymous projection notation (dot notation) for function application?
I often see the so-called "anonymous projection notation" in Lean 4's Infoview, which uses dot . to express function applications. For example:
⊢ m.succ.add n = (m.add n).succ

If I understand it correctly, it is equivalent to a plain function call:
⊢ add (succ m) n = succ (add m n)

It's a matter of taste, but I find the dot style (anonymous projection notation) distracting and more difficult to read, as I have to constantly switch between two different orders while reading function applications, i.e. left-to-right style (f x y) and right-to-left style (x.f y). This is true especially when reading a longer statement.
Is there a way in Lean 4 and VSCode to disable the dot notation (anonymous projection notation) and only display in the plain function call style in the Infoview?

x.f indeed desugars to a plain old function application, but not necessarily f x.  Indeed, the lookup for f will happen in the namespace of the type of x, not the current namespace.  So, if x : Some.Path.To.T, x.f can desugar to Some.Path.To.T.f x.

The option that covers the pretty printing in field notation (with a dot) is pp.fieldNotation.  You can disable it with set_option pp.fieldNotation false.
